# Keras - model.summary does not display the summary. Instead it says something like '<... object at 0x12ff2dad0>>'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

here is the (I think) important part of the code:

```
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(vgg_model)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    print(model.summary)
```

what I get in the console, instead of the model summary is this:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2019-11-17 01:53:56.153721: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-17 01:53:56.167311: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fe2a265c6c0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-17 01:53:56.167326: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
<bound method Network.summary of <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x12ff2dad0>>
```

I hope the mistake is not somewhere else. Please help.

P.S. I tried asking for the summary of just the vgg_model. it was the same thing.

P.P.S. it does not matter if I run this on my MacBook or windows PC. I tried different tf and Keras versions. always the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`model.summary` accesses the `summary` method of the `model` object. To  *call* the method, use `()`:

```py
model.summary()  # no need for print()
```